# WPF Databinding Treeview to List does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a List bound to a TreeView like:

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="browserTree" 
          BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray"
          BorderThickness="1"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Margin="0,3,0,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

C#:

```
browserTree.DataContext = treeList;
```

I update the list via:

```
void QueryChange(string s)
{
    rCM.SetCommand(s);
    treeList.Clear();
    SqlDataReader sr = rCM.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);
    while (sr.Read())
    {
        treeList.Add((string)sr["tree_hdr"]);
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

The `List<string>` is just a placeholder at the moment for a more meaningful data class I have yet to implement. But right now I need to know why the TreeView is not updating to reflect the changes made to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the treelist an ObservableCollection.

Comment: The observable collection will tell the ui when it has been updated, so the UI object can update itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the type of your treeList which you set as DataContext. It has to be an ObservableCollection to reflect your collection changes in the UI

Or else for quick workaround, just set the DataContext again after you filled the List.